# MVVMLight toolkit RaisePropertyChanged doesn't seem to update UI when DataContext stays on the same object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am having a hard time understanding what I am doing wrong. Basically I am trying to implement a "Cancel" feature on a form.

I have a Model which implements the ObservableObject of the toolkit and maps to an EF entity class. When I call my CancelChanges() method, it basically does a context.Refresh() with StoreWins.

Now I have a ViewModel with the following property :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="CurrentDairyProduct" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string CurrentDairyProductPropertyName = "CurrentDairyProduct";

    private DairyProduct _currentDairyProduct = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the CurrentDairyProduct property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public DairyProduct CurrentDairyProduct
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentDairyProduct;
        }

        set
        {
            RaisePropertyChanging(CurrentDairyProductPropertyName);
            _currentDairyProduct = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(CurrentDairyProductPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

And a View with this form

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,14,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  DataContext="{Binding Path=CurrentDairyProduct, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
  Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="DAIRY PRODUCT CODE:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Path=DairyProductCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
        <Label Content="DAIRY PRODUCT NAME EN:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Path=DairyProductNameEn, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
        <Label Content="DAIRY PRODUCT NAME FR:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Path=DairyProductNameFr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />

    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Save" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="342,332,0,0" Name="button1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" />
    <Button Content="Cancel" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="442,332,0,0" Name="button2" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Command="{Binding Path=CancelCommand}" />
```

Everything works well when I call the following statement to get the data from the database

```
CurrentDairyProduct = _dairyProductRepository.GetObservableObjectById(_currentDairyProductId);
```

The View is updated with all the data from my Model.

I can make changes to the View which are then transferred over to my model without a problem

Now the CancelCommand

```
protected override void CancelChanges()
{
    CurrentDairyProduct = _dairyProductRepository.CancelChanges(_currentDairyProduct);

}
```

This should in theory call the setter of CurrentDairyProduct which in turn calls the RaisePropertyChanged. This works as I can Debug into it. Unfortunately, the View doesn't get updated at all.

Out of curiosity I changed my CancelCommand code to the following:

```
protected override void CancelChanges()
{
    //CurrentDairyProduct = _dairyProductRepository.CancelChanges(_currentDairyProduct);
    DairyProduct temp = _dairyProductRepository.CancelChanges(_currentDairyProduct);
    CurrentDairyProduct = null;
    CurrentDairyProduct = temp;
 }
```

With this code, the View does get updated...

My question is what am I supposed to do to update the View if the actual DataContext stays on the same object but it's properties change. Is there a way to force an update without using this temp variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be that you are trying to update CurrentDairyProduct with its own backing field. I would guess that you pass the _currentDairyProduct to your repository method and directly manipulate it, then return it. By doing so, you do not trigger the INPC and therefore no view updates happeN. When you try to assign it back to your CurrentDairyProduct, the value is now the same and therefore INPC doesn't trigger either. When you set it to null and reassign CurrentDairyProduct, a change is detected and therefore INPC is triggered.

One way to fix this would be to create a new instance DairyProduct in your CancelChanges method on your repository and return that instead of manipulating _currentDairyProduct.
CurrentDairyProduct will then detect a new value and trigger INPC.

An better alternative might be to pass CurrentDairyProduct instead of _currentDairyProduct. Changes to CurrentDairyProduct would trigger INPC.

I believe if you make a variable private it has no business getting manipulated outside of its scope. I mean that's why you have a public version right?

Comment: I had tried both version of passing the public and private variable to the same result. I figured as much for the INPC not picking up changes to my entity as there's no actual trigger with it. Ill try the new instance part once I'm back on that project. Thanks.